# How do I call function that has pointer before it

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-declaration

I am struggling with calling function that has pointer before it. We have school project to code our own malloc version. Problem is following:

I call function like this: `char *ptrr = (char*)memory_alloc(10);`

Function header is this: `void *memory_alloc(unsigned int size)`

And i get fault like this: Cast from pointer to integer of different size.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: The provided code is val;id. The error occurs somewhere else.

Comment: What is your platform/compiler/OS/IDE/...? You need to provide a [mcve] including the verbatim error log.

Comment: Well, did not expect that it is valid. I use  Dev-C++ compiler, will try to switch to visual studio. Thanks

Comment: Switching compilers will not fix the problem. You need to work with the code that is getting the error message, which is not the code currently shown in the question.

Comment: Just to note a few things you will definitely need to learn: 1. This is not a header! - it is a *function declaration* or *prototype*. 2. It is not called "*fault*", it is called "*warning*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compiler suspects that you are trying to cast a pointer to an integer.
Usually, we get this warning when we try to write something like this:

```
void myFunction (int i) 
{
    // ....
}

int main()
{
    void *p; // = NULL, malloc, calloc, ...

    myFunction ( (int) p);

    return 0;
}
```

I suggest you look in your code (ideally post it in your question), if you don't have a cast like this.